# How to edit a specific child's value in Firebase from Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Can you help me identify why my code is not working? I want to retrieve the value of the child `rate` in Firebase and display it on my `EditText` in Android Studio. Then when another value is entered in the `EditText` via `button`, the value of the child `rate` will be updated. Thanks.

```
package com.example.jordan.grat;

import ...

public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mLogout, mAddDriver, mEditDriver, mUpdateRate;

private DatabaseReference mAdminDatabase;

private EditText mRateField;

private String mRate, mPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

    mLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
    mAddDriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDriver);
    mEditDriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editDriver);
    mUpdateRate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateRate);

    mRateField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rateField);

    mAdminDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Admins");

    getRate();

    mAddDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, AddDriverActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });

    mEditDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

    mLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });

    mUpdateRate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setRate();
        }
    });
}

private void getRate() {
    mAdminDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if (map.get("rate")!=null){
                    mRate = map.get("rate").toString();
                    mRateField.setText(mRate);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

private void setRate() {
    mRateField.getText().toString();
    mAdminDatabase.child("rate").setValue(mRateField);
}

}
```

I am sorry, I am still a beginner in Android Studio. Any help would be appreciated. My firebase:

[image]

Comment: The problem could be in the auth. By default, you need to be logged in to read and write the database. Check the rules in firebase.

Comment: @Juanje Ohh I see, I didn't know that. Is there a way where I can somehow make the restriction public and not only for users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the rules in the `FirebaseDatabase`. If you set them to `true`, there is no need to auth. Btw, this is a not recommended option, you should always have some security in this aspect.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your Firebase rules. I saw that you asked for "make the restriction public", so you can open your rules and set read and write true.

Like this:

```json
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mAdminDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("Admins");
```

Should it works :D

If it doesn't work try this :

```
  mUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

and after that, you can set the value of the admins

```
  mUser.child("Admins").child("rate").setValue("aString");
```

Comment: I just changed the restrictions. Thank you though.

Answer (score -1):

It's working try this:

```
private Button mLogout, mAddDriver, mEditDriver, mUpdateRate;

    private DatabaseReference mAdminDatabase;

    private EditText mRateField;

    private String mRate, mPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mUpdateRate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        mRateField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        mAdminDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Admins");

        getRate();

        mUpdateRate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setRate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getRate() {
        mAdminDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if (map.get("rate")!=null){
                        mRate = map.get("rate").toString();
                        mRateField.setText(mRate);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void setRate() {
        mRate =   mRateField.getText().toString();
        mAdminDatabase.child("rate").setValue(mRate);
    }
```

Hope It's help full.
[image]

Comment: Your setRate function has error, please assign the value of an edit text to a variable or assign the edittext value directly to the   mAdminDatabase.child("rate").setValue(mRateField.getText().toString());

Comment: I just changed the restrictions. Thank you though.